# Hibernate many-to-one - bad usage?

Tags: hibernate

Just trying out Hibernate (with Annotations) and I'm having problems with my mappings. I have two entity classes, AudioCD and Artist.

```
@Entity
public class AudioCD implements CatalogItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, optional = false)
    private Artist artist;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name" }) })
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    .....
}
```

I get AudioCD objects from an external source. When I try to persist the AudioCD the Artist gets persisted as well, just like I want to happen. If I try persisting another different CD, but Artist already exists I get errors due to constraint violations.

I want Hibernate to recognise that the Artist already exists and shouldn't be inserted again. Can this be done via annotations? Or do I have to manage the persistence of the AudioCD and Artist seperately?

Comment: Are you loading the `Artist` from the database first? It should work if you load the `Artist` from the database then set it to the `AudioCD`. Then it knows that that `Artist` already exists and it wont try to create a new one.

Comment: No, I get an AudioCD object with a reference to an Artist object. Neither have come from the database. Could I attempt to 'attach' the Artist object to an Artist in the database? Then persist the AudioCD as the second step? Sounds like that is what incarnate is suggesting below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK you can't.

Since `name` is unique for every `Artist` instance, you should try to lookup an artist by name (via `session.createCriteria(Artist.class).add(Restrictions.eq("name", artistName)).uniqueResult()` or get yourself some service class with method `Artist findByName(String artistName)`) and then decide, whether to persist an artist or to use existing one.